# Return every instance of a string contains search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have this sample table and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TextColumn] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (1, N'This is the first Test string')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (2, N'This is the second one')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (3, N'This is the first really long string of text that should be included in the result set.')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (4, N'This is the second long string that will not be returned in the result set')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (5, N'This is a really really long result set that should also be first included in the result set.  It has a seperate sentence in it as well.')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (6, N'Now this is a really really first one.   It is so long that I have forgotten how long it really was.   Well it could be really long but first lets do this.  ')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] OFF
```

With The Below Query

```
;with cte as (SELECT  
      a.Id ,
      a.TextColumn, 
      CASE When LEN(TextColumn) <= 60
          Then TextColumn 
          ELSE LEFT(TextColumn, 60) + '...'
          END As Target,
          charindex('first', TextColumn) as SearchPos
  FROM
       SampleTable a 
       WHERE Contains((TextColumn), '%first%'))

select *, case when SearchPos > 20 then substring(TextColumn, SearchPos - 20, 20) + 'first' + 
substring(TextColumn, SearchPos + len('first'), 20) else substring(TextColumn, 1, SearchPos-1) + 'first' + substring(TextColumn, SearchPos + len('first'), 20)
 end as NewString
from cte
```

I am trying to return every instance of a word with a Contains search.  But the string could be in the middle of a large sting.  So I am returning the string and a given length to the left and right of the searched string.  Sort of like a summary.  If the word occurs multiple times it is only returning the first instance and moving on to the next instance.  How can I get it to return all instances even multiple ones in the same cell.  So the item with Id of 6 should return twice not once because I am looking for the string 'first'.  I am using Sql Server 2012. The New String Column Is What I am shooting for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following query if you want to count the number of occurrence of the string `'first'` in the `TextColumn` each row.

```
SELECT (LEN(TextColumn) - 
LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, 'first', '')))/LEN('first') as NumOfOccurrence, 
TextColumn FROM dbo.SampleTable;
```

**Update**: To cover the trailing space case (as caught by Twinkles in the following comment), I modified the query as below.

```
SELECT (LEN(TextColumn) - 
LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, 'a ', '')))/(LEN('a ' + 'x') - 1) as NumOfOccurrence, 
TextColumn, id FROM dbo.SampleTable;
```

Following code gets the multiple instances in a `New String Column`, with separator defined as `@sep` and search word defined as `@word`, where `@sep <> @ word`:

```
declare @sep as char(2);
declare @word as varchar(24);
set @sep = ', ';
set @word = 'first';

SELECT  ID, TextColumn, ISNULL(STUFF(REPLICATE(@sep + @word, (LEN(TextColumn) - 
LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, @word, '')))/(LEN(@word + 'x') - 1)), 1, 1, ''), '') 
as [New String Column] FROM dbo.SampleTable;
```

Comment: LEN() returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**. Your query returns wrong results if somebody for instance wants to exclude substrings inside of words by appending a blank.

Comment: Good catch - Thanks Twinkles. Using `(LEN(@SearchText + 'x') - 1)` as divisor in the above query should solve it. I have updated the query to reflect the change.